# automatic number increase in php based web form

Tags: php, forms, pdf, webforms

So I have created an html form which then posts the results to a php file that overlays them on a PDF and then emails that PDF to myself and the email that was put in the form. All I want to do now is find a simple way to make it so that the PDF includes a sequential number.

For example: When the form is filled out for the first time the number 0001 is input automatically into the PDF and 0002 for the second time and so on.

Is there an easy PHP function to accomplish this?

Essentially I am creating an online invoicing form so when I do service calls I can create an invoice on the spot from a web browser which is then emailed to my office and the client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have to build your own logic for this.

Comment: could I say theoretically use a page counter that is hidden and the PHP just inputs the number from the page counter? Or is there a better solution you might be able to direct me in?

Comment: Or would there be a way to maybe use the current date and time down to the minute to print to the PDF?

Comment: you can use the `time()` function of `php` which returns the current timestamp

Comment: ok so if I wanted to use a variable like $invoicenumber  =  the current time
how exactly could I do that.  Forgive me I am a novice php coder.

Comment: $invoicenumber = time(); - This will always be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an incrementing number, you could keep a number in a database and then extract it, add 1 to it, use it, and then put it back in the DB for next time, but this seems complicated. Somebody in the comments mentioned using the timestamp, which would be done like so:

```
$invoicenumber = time(); //This number will always be unique
```

The time function works like so (copied from w3schools):

> The time() function returns the current time in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).
>   Since actual seconds can only go up (increment), this number will never be the same twice.

I hope this is helpful.

-Edit

You can also display this date/time in a readable format like so:

```
$time = time();
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time);
```

-Edit 2

If you want an incrementing number, you basically need a very simple database to save it, which might be as simple as a table called invoices, with a column called invoicenumber, which stores your invoice number in it. You could / probably should use this to store other invoice information in it too, so you'd have each invoice number saved (which means we want to only get the highest one)

Then your code would look like this, for each time you want to use it:

Firstly you'd have a database information file (settings.php or something similar) with your database definitions in it, which might look like this:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'db_username');
define('DB_PASS', 'db_password');
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name');
```

Your code would look like this:

```
//Establish a mysql connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

//Set up a query to get the highest number
$query = "SELECT invoicenumber FROM invoices ORDER BY invoicenumber DESC LIMIT 1";

//Get the result
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

//If we have a record
if($row){
    //New invoice number
    $invoicenumber = $row['invoicenumber']++;
//Else (database is empty, so start at the beginning)
}else{
    $invoicenumber = 1;
}

//Now we have our invoice number, so do whatever you want with it
/**
 * Code here to use the number
 * */

//Now we wanna add the new invoice to the database, so
/**
 * Add any other info to this statement if you want.
 * If any of it is user submitted data, be sure to use prepared statements 
 * (just look at php.net's documentation on prepared statements)
 * w3schools also has some nice tutorials on how to safely insert stuff
 * in to a database, so check it all out :)
 * */
$query = "INSERT INTO invoices(invoicenumber) VALUES($invoicenumber)";

//Execute the query
if($mysqli->query($query)){
    //Show success
    echo "Invoice $invoicenumber has been added to the database.";
}else{
    //Show error
    echo "Unfortunately we could not add invoice $invoicenumber to the database.";
}

//Now we can clear up our resources
$stmt->free_result(); $stmt->close(); $mysqli->close();
```

Please note: this is a very basic example. Yours will have additions and enhanced security if you are using user submitted data, so please do your homework and make sure that you fully understand each line of this code before you proceed to use it.

Comment: Thank you this works pretty much perfectly.  I wish there was an easy way to just simply start with 0001 and work my way up so there isn't drastic differences between the invoice numbers from one invoice to the next. But this definitely works in a pinch.

Comment: This can be done too, just keep the value in a database to save it, and increment it for each invoice.

Comment: Ok, since I am trying to learn PHP and SQL I am going to use google and try to figure this out. I've gotten this far. BTW how to I post my code in here without going over the character limit? Stupid question I know lol.

Comment: You can't post a lot of code in the comments section but you can post small chunks by surrounding it with the ( ` ) backtick, so that `it looks like this`

Comment: So how did Misunderstood do it in the comment below? he managed to post and entire page.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you what I mean - I believe misunderstood is taking the number from the pdf file itself, and has also posted their entire pdf2text function page. I'd personally advise using a database to store as much information as you might need in the future about each corresponding invoice, as this way you don't need to parse the invoices every time you want to gather a time/date, name, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much!  After fiddling around with parts of that script you gave me I now have the form doing exactly what I wanted it to do this whole time.  Every time I create a new invoice the number increases 1 by 1.  Thanks a million for your patience and generous help.

Answer (score 0):

I do exactly the same with patient accession numbers on patient reports.

```
include('/home/user/php/class.pdf2text.php');
$p2t = new PDF2Text();

$p2t->setFilename($pdf);
$p2t->decodePDF();
$data = $p2t->output();
$len = strlen($data);
$pos = strpos($data,$accession);

if (pos){
  $in .= "$accession,";
  $checked++;
}
else{
  $missingPDF += 1;echo "\n<p>&#x2002;<span class='bold red'>INCORRECT ACCESSION NUMBER c=$row[0] p=$row[1]</span>\n";
   }

if ($checked > 0){
  $in = substr($in,0,-1) . ')';
  $sql = "UPDATE `Patient` SET `PDF`=1 WHERE $in";
}
```

**pdf2text.php**

```
class PDF2Text {
  // Some settings
  var $multibyte = 4; // Use setUnicode(TRUE|FALSE)
  var $convertquotes = ENT_QUOTES; // ENT_COMPAT (double-quotes), ENT_QUOTES (Both), ENT_NOQUOTES (None)
  var $showprogress = true; // TRUE if you have problems with time-out
   // Variables
  var $filename = '';
  var $decodedtext = '';
   function setFilename($filename) {
    // Reset
    $this->decodedtext = '';
    $this->filename = $filename;
  }
   function output($echo = false) {
    if($echo) echo $this->decodedtext;
    else return $this->decodedtext;
  }
   function setUnicode($input) {
    // 4 for unicode. But 2 should work in most cases just fine
    if($input == true) $this->multibyte = 4;
    else $this->multibyte = 2;
  }
   function decodePDF() {
    // Read the data from pdf file
    $infile = @file_get_contents($this->filename, FILE_BINARY);
    if (empty($infile))
      return "";
     // Get all text data.
    $transformations = array();
    $texts = array();
     // Get the list of all objects.
    preg_match_all("#obj[\n|\r](.*)endobj[\n|\r]#ismU", $infile . "endobj\r", $objects);
    $objects = @$objects[1];
     // Select objects with streams.
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects); $i++) {
      $currentObject = $objects[$i];
       // Prevent time-out
      @set_time_limit ();
      if($this->showprogress) {
//            echo ". ";
        flush(); ob_flush();
      }
       // Check if an object includes data stream.
      if (preg_match("#stream[\n|\r](.*)endstream[\n|\r]#ismU", $currentObject . "endstream\r", $stream )) {
        $stream = ltrim($stream[1]);
        // Check object parameters and look for text data.
        $options = $this->getObjectOptions($currentObject);
         if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) && empty($options["Type"]) && empty($options["Subtype"])) )
//            if ( $options["Image"] && $options["Subtype"] )
//            if (!(empty($options["Length1"]) &&  empty($options["Subtype"])) )
          continue;
         // Hack, length doesnt always seem to be correct
        unset($options["Length"]);
         // So, we have text data. Decode it.
        $data = $this->getDecodedStream($stream, $options);
         if (strlen($data)) {
      if (preg_match_all("#BT[\n|\r](.*)ET[\n|\r]#ismU", $data . "ET\r", $textContainers)) {
            $textContainers = @$textContainers[1];
            $this->getDirtyTexts($texts, $textContainers);
          } else
            $this->getCharTransformations($transformations, $data);
        }
      }
    }
     // Analyze text blocks taking into account character transformations and return results.
    $this->decodedtext = $this->getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations);
  }

   function decodeAsciiHex($input) {
    $output = "";
     $isOdd = true;
    $isComment = false;
     for($i = 0, $codeHigh = -1; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '>'; $i++) {
      $c = $input[$i];
       if($isComment) {
        if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
          $isComment = false;
        continue;
      }
       switch($c) {
        case '\0': case '\t': case '\r': case '\f': case '\n': case ' ': break;
        case '%':
          $isComment = true;
        break;
         default:
          $code = hexdec($c);
          if($code === 0 && $c != '0')
            return "";
           if($isOdd)
            $codeHigh = $code;
          else
            $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16 + $code);
           $isOdd = !$isOdd;
        break;
      }
    }
     if($input[$i] != '>')
      return "";
     if($isOdd)
      $output .= chr($codeHigh * 16);
     return $output;
  }
   function decodeAscii85($input) {
    $output = "";
     $isComment = false;
    $ords = array();
     for($i = 0, $state = 0; $i < strlen($input) && $input[$i] != '~'; $i++) {
      $c = $input[$i];
       if($isComment) {
        if ($c == '\r' || $c == '\n')
          $isComment = false;
        continue;
      }
       if ($c == '\0' || $c == '\t' || $c == '\r' || $c == '\f' || $c == '\n' || $c == ' ')
        continue;
      if ($c == '%') {
        $isComment = true;
        continue;
      }
      if ($c == 'z' && $state === 0) {
        $output .= str_repeat(chr(0), 4);
        continue;
      }
      if ($c < '!' || $c > 'u')
        return "";
       $code = ord($input[$i]) & 0xff;
      $ords[$state++] = $code - ord('!');
       if ($state == 5) {
        $state = 0;
        for ($sum = 0, $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++)
          $sum = $sum * 85 + $ords[$j];
        for ($j = 3; $j >= 0; $j--)
          $output .= chr($sum >> ($j * 8));
      }
    }
    if ($state === 1)
      return "";
    elseif ($state > 1) {
      for ($i = 0, $sum = 0; $i < $state; $i++)
        $sum += ($ords[$i] + ($i == $state - 1)) * pow(85, 4 - $i);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $state - 1; $i++) {
        try {
          if(false == ($o = chr($sum >> ((3 - $i) * 8)))) {
            throw new Exception('Error');
          }
          $output .= $o;
        } catch (Exception $e) { /*Dont do anything*/ }
      }
    }
     return $output;
  }
   function decodeFlate($data) {
    return @gzuncompress($data);
  }
   function getObjectOptions($object) {
    $options = array();
     if (preg_match("#<<(.*)>>#ismU", $object, $options)) {
      $options = explode("/", $options[1]);
      @array_shift($options);
       $o = array();
      for ($j = 0; $j < @count($options); $j++) {
        $options[$j] = preg_replace("#\s+#", " ", trim($options[$j]));
        if (strpos($options[$j], " ") !== false) {
          $parts = explode(" ", $options[$j]);
          $o[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
        } else
          $o[$options[$j]] = true;
      }
      $options = $o;
      unset($o);
    }
     return $options;
  }
   function getDecodedStream($stream, $options) {
    $data = "";
    if (empty($options["Filter"]))
      $data = $stream;
    else {
      $length = !empty($options["Length"]) ? $options["Length"] : strlen($stream);
      $_stream = substr($stream, 0, $length);
       foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "ASCIIHexDecode")
          $_stream = $this->decodeAsciiHex($_stream);
        elseif ($key == "ASCII85Decode")
          $_stream = $this->decodeAscii85($_stream);
        elseif ($key == "FlateDecode")
          $_stream = $this->decodeFlate($_stream);
        elseif ($key == "Crypt") { // TO DO
        }
      }
      $data = $_stream;
    }
    return $data;
  }
   function getDirtyTexts(&$texts, $textContainers) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($textContainers); $j++) {
      if (preg_match_all("#\[(.*)\]\s*TJ[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
        $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
      elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\(.*\))\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
        $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
      elseif (preg_match_all("#T[d|w|m|f]\s*(\[.*\])\s*Tj[\n|\r]#ismU", $textContainers[$j], $parts))
        $texts = array_merge($texts, array(@implode('', $parts[1])));
    }
   }
   function getCharTransformations(&$transformations, $stream) {
    preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfchar(.*)endbfchar#ismU", $stream, $chars, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    preg_match_all("#([0-9]+)\s+beginbfrange(.*)endbfrange#ismU", $stream, $ranges, PREG_SET_ORDER);
     for ($j = 0; $j < count($chars); $j++) {
      $count = $chars[$j][1];
      $current = explode("\n", trim($chars[$j][2]));
      for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
        if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{2,4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4,512})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map))
          $transformations[str_pad($map[1], 4, "0")] = $map[2];
      }
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($ranges); $j++) {
      $count = $ranges[$j][1];
      $current = explode("\n", trim($ranges[$j][2]));
      for ($k = 0; $k < $count && $k < count($current); $k++) {
        if (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>#is", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
          $from = hexdec($map[1]);
          $to = hexdec($map[2]);
          $_from = hexdec($map[3]);
           for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to; $m++, $n++)
            $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", $_from + $n);
        } elseif (preg_match("#<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+<([0-9a-f]{4})>\s+\[(.*)\]#ismU", trim($current[$k]), $map)) {
          $from = hexdec($map[1]);
          $to = hexdec($map[2]);
          $parts = preg_split("#\s+#", trim($map[3]));
           for ($m = $from, $n = 0; $m <= $to && $n < count($parts); $m++, $n++)
            $transformations[sprintf("%04X", $m)] = sprintf("%04X", hexdec($parts[$n]));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  function getTextUsingTransformations($texts, $transformations) {
    $document = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($texts); $i++) {
      $isHex = false;
      $isPlain = false;
       $hex = "";
      $plain = "";
      for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($texts[$i]); $j++) {
        $c = $texts[$i][$j];
        switch($c) {
          case "<":
            $hex = "";
            $isHex = true;
      $isPlain = false;
          break;
          case ">":
            $hexs = str_split($hex, $this->multibyte); // 2 or 4 (UTF8 or ISO)
            for ($k = 0; $k < count($hexs); $k++) {
               $chex = str_pad($hexs[$k], 4, "0"); // Add tailing zero
              if (isset($transformations[$chex]))
                $chex = $transformations[$chex];
              $document .= html_entity_decode("&#x".$chex.";");
            }
            $isHex = false;
          break;
          case "(":
            $plain = "";
            $isPlain = true;
      $isHex = false;
          break;
          case ")":
            $document .= $plain;
            $isPlain = false;
          break;
          case "\\":
            $c2 = $texts[$i][$j + 1];
            if (in_array($c2, array("\\", "(", ")"))) $plain .= $c2;
            elseif ($c2 == "n") $plain .= '\n';
            elseif ($c2 == "r") $plain .= '\r';
            elseif ($c2 == "t") $plain .= '\t';
            elseif ($c2 == "b") $plain .= '\b';
            elseif ($c2 == "f") $plain .= '\f';
            elseif ($c2 >= '0' && $c2 <= '9') {
              $oct = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", substr($texts[$i], $j + 1, 3));
              $j += strlen($oct) - 1;
              $plain .= html_entity_decode("&#".octdec($oct).";", $this->convertquotes);
            }
            $j++;
          break;
           default:
            if ($isHex)
              $hex .= $c;
            elseif ($isPlain)
              $plain .= $c;
          break;
        }
      }
      $document .= "\n";
    }
     return $document;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok I am a complete novice with PHP. This is my current processor.php code.  Any idea what I should add and where to make a sequential number show up?

'code'

Comment: ok im not sure how to add code to my comment lol